# How can I switch column sizes between various screen sizes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

With Bootstrap 3.3.6, is there a way I can change the width of columns classes (i.e. col-md-3) depending on the screen size? I would like to go from a  col-md-3 to a col-sm-3), on the same element.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole idea of bootstrap is to use the different size qualifiers.
Perhaps what you mean to do is have col-md-3 together with col-xs-2 in the same class attribute of the the div so the switchig is automatic when the screen size matches xs or md.

Comment: Let me test this...thanks for thinking this through with me

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.  You said what I was trying to question.  Many thanks!